# ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION get network disconected from in API >= 14?

Tags: android, networking, connectivity

I need to get the network from which device was disconnected.

Now I use:

```
NetworkInfo ni =intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
```

And check:

```
ni.isConnected()
```

if this returns false ni - is the network from which the device was disconnected.

But `ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO` is *deprecated* in API 14. Google says use getActiveNetworkInfo() to get network information. But getActiveNetworkInfo() always returns network with which the device is connected now (`isConnected()` must return true)!

How do I get the network info for the network the device disconnected from without using ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO?

Sertorio Noronha, when I use getActiveNetworkInfo() I only get the network to which I am connected now! But I need to get the network from which I was disconnected.

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)
    context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo n1 = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
Log.d("tets", String.format("%s: %s", n1.getTypeName(), n1.isConnected()));
```

When I disconnect from WI-FI and connect to 3G in log:

```
mobile: true
mobile: true
```

When I disconnect from 3G and connect to WI-FI in log:

```
WIFI: true
WIFI: true
WIFI: true
```

getActiveNetworkInfo returns only the network connected to now, but does not return the network from which I was disconnected.

If I use deprecated intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO) in log I see:

When I disconnect from WI-FI and connect to 3G:

```
WIFI: false
mobile: true
```

When I disconnect from 3G and connect to WI-FI:

```
mobile: false
WIFI: true
```

But I do not want to use deprecated api. How to use modern api to get network from which I was disconnected?

Answer (score 11):

You can use the following

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
int networkType = intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_TYPE);
boolean isWiFi = networkType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI;
boolean isMobile = networkType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE;
NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(networkType);
boolean isConnected = networkInfo.isConnected();

if (isWiFi) {
    if (isConnected) {
        Log.i("APP_TAG", "Wi-Fi - CONNECTED");
    } else {
        Log.i("APP_TAG", "Wi-Fi - DISCONNECTED");
    }
} else if (isMobile) {
    if (isConnected) {
        Log.i("APP_TAG", "Mobile - CONNECTED");
    } else {
        Log.i("APP_TAG", "Mobile - DISCONNECTED");
    }
} else {
    if (isConnected) {
        Log.i("APP_TAG", networkInfo.getTypeName() + " - CONNECTED");
    } else {
        Log.i("APP_TAG", networkInfo.getTypeName() + " - DISCONNECTED");
    }
}
```

Comment: use extras.getInt for EXTRA_NETWORK_TYPE also this field was introduced in API 17

Answer (score 6):

You  can get the instance of NetworkInfo through the Context.

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = ((ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE));
NetworkInfo currentNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

if(currentNetworkInfo != null && currentNetworkInfo.isConnected()){
   // Your logic goes in here
}
```

Comment: Please use getTypeName() from the class NetworkInfo. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html

Comment: Your response does not answer my question! Look at topic header, I provide additional info.

Comment: A very easy solution will be to store the previous value in a local String. Your problem can be solved with simple logic.

Comment: this was the solution for me, since i needed api level 14-16 too

Answer (score 6):

**Working non deprecated code**

```
/**Receiver*/   

 public class NetworkStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        /*
         * @see android.content.BroadcastReceiver#onReceive(android.content.Context,
         * android.content.Intent)
         */
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            int networkType = intent.getExtras().getInt(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_TYPE);
            boolean isWiFi = networkType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI;
            boolean isMobile = networkType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE;
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(networkType);
            boolean isConnected = networkInfo.isConnected();

            if (isWiFi) {
                if (isConnected) {
                    Log.i("APP_TAG", "Wi-Fi - CONNECTED");
                } else {
                    Log.i("APP_TAG", "Wi-Fi - DISCONNECTED");
                }
            } else if (isMobile) {
                if (isConnected) {
                    Log.i("APP_TAG", "Mobile - CONNECTED");
                } else {
                    Log.i("APP_TAG", "Mobile - DISCONNECTED");
                }
            } else {
                if (isConnected) {
                    Log.i("APP_TAG", networkInfo.getTypeName() + " - CONNECTED");
                } else {
                    Log.i("APP_TAG", networkInfo.getTypeName() + " - DISCONNECTED");
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

And in manifest

```
<!-- Receiver registration in manifest -->
     <receiver android:name="com.xxx.yyy.NetworkStateReceiver" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
```

and

```
<!-- Internet permission for network comunication -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` is deprecated in Android N - FYI

Comment: Thanks for comment this has been written ver long days back will update as per new Android N soon

Comment: @behelit I thought CONNECTIVITY_ACTION was depcrecated in Android N ? https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html

Comment: Its not deprecated, it will only trigger apps that are foreground and listening. If your app registered for this event and is stopped or in background it wont be notified.